# Did Narada Muni hate his mother in his previous birth?

Tags: puranas, bhagavata-purana, narada

I could not stop thinking about this. How could the divine Deva rishi Narada, in his own previous birth as a Brahmin, hate his own mother?

Whilst re-reading the Srimad Bhagavatam for a second time, I seem to have overlooked this in Skandha I, Chapter 6:

> 6. My mother, to whom I was the only son, **being an ignorant woman**—a maid servant—**bound me by (her) affection** as I was a son who had no other shelter.
> 7. Although she desired (to provide) for my well-being, she, being not independent, was unable to do so. People are subject to (the Will of) the Almighty like a doll of wood.
> 8. And I, as a child of five years of age, being ignorant of directions, regions or time, stayed in the Brāhmaṇa’s house expecting that (termination of the bond of maternal affection).
> 9. Once, when my innocent mother went out at night (to milk the cow), a serpent (as if) ordered by the god of death, was touched by her foot on the way, bit her while she was milking (the cow).
> 10. **Then, looking upon it (my mother’s death) as the grace of the Lord** who is solicitous about the well-being of his devotees, I proceeded to the northern direction.
> 11. (While going alone) in that direction, I saw prosperous countries and capital towns, villages, habitations of cowherds and mines, villages of cultivators, habitations adjacent to hills and streams, parks, jungles and gardens.

Looking at the Sanskrit text for verses 6 and 10:

> ekātmajā me jananī
> yoṣin **mūḍhā** ca kinkarī
> mayy ātmaje 'nanya-gatau
> cakre **snehānubandhanam** (6)

Here, *mūdhā* means "ignorant" or "foolish." Furthermore, *snehānubandanam* means a person "tied by affection."

> **tadā tad aham īśasya
> bhaktānām śam** abhīpsataḥ
> anugraham manyamānaḥ
> prātiṣṭham diśam uttarām

Here, *tadā tad aham iśasya bhaktānām śam* means "thinking this to be the Lord's grace." Why would Narada Muni think his mother's death is the Lord's grace?

By insulting his mother by calling her "foolish" or "ignorant" and thanking the Lord for freeing him from the bind of affection, does this not resemble hate?

An Acharya's commentary on these verses would be very helpful.

Comment: According to the Brahmavaivarta Purana, Narada was the mental son of Brahma who refused to procreate progeny due to his predisposition towards vairagya. So Brahma cursed him to undergo through the womb twice. In his first birth Narada was born as the Gandharva Upabarhana & in the second birth as the dasiputra of a Brahmin. In that birth he was enlightened by the grace of Sanatkumara & regained back his divine form. If seen from the levels of vairagya of the likes of Sanatkumara, Narada's distaste towards his mother is natural like any other sannyasi's distaste towards their relatives.

Comment: Distaste & hate are not the same thing. Hate is generated from kama & krodha while distaste in this sense, is generated from a wise person reminiscing his past foolishness. Secondly, Narada comparing his earthly mother's death as divine grace isn't abnormal if seen from his state of vairagya, because as a dasiputra, he had no obligations towards his Brahmin father & his mother was the only thing holding him back to samsara. A renunciate is bound to hate the samsara due to his/her inherent tendencies similar to how a bird will hate being caged & prefer the insecurities of living amongst nature.

Comment: @AnubrataBit Sorry for the late response, but thank you for the answer! This does make sense. If you want, you can make this comment an answer, and I'll be more than happy to upvote it and select it as the preferred answer!